# daysOfWeekDisabled option does not work on DateTimePicker plug in

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know there are other questions like mine, but I just wanted to know if there is an update on this problem. I am using Bootstrap.v3.Datetimepicker.CSS by Eonasdan v4.17.45 package.

The code is as is supposted to be:

```
    $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'd.m.Y H:i',
        minTime: '08:30',
        maxTime: '17:30',
        minDate: 0,
        step: 30,
        closeOnDateSelect: false,
        closeOnTimeSelect: false,
        daysOfWeekDisabled: [0,6],
        useCurrent: false
    })
```

Comment: Can you show some example or can you fiddle it

Comment: Also use id selector for accessing datepicker